# Find duplicate names with different dob tsql (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the only duplicate names with different dob with dob in the result set. I don't want non-duplicate rows.

I tried CTE and combination of Group By and Having.

```
declare @person table (id int, e_name nvarchar(50), dob datetime)

INSERT @person VALUES (1,'Jack Hughens','1960-11-02')
INSERT @person VALUES (2,'Tom Hughens','1971-01-08')
INSERT @person VALUES (3,'Sam Scallion','1960-11-02')
INSERT @person VALUES (4,'Sam Scallion','1960-11-01')
INSERT @person VALUES (5,'Paul Darty','1994-10-19')
INSERT @person VALUES (6,'Paul Ashley','1983-09-21')
```

The result should be as below:

```
--------------------------------
|id|e_name         |dob         |
--------------------------------
|3|Sam Scallion   |1960-11-02  |
--------------------------------
|4|Sam Scallion   |1960-11-01  |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: If you are authorized to declassify your code, please add it to your question. Then we can help figure out why it didn't work.

Comment: _dob datetime_  Why, just why? You only record the date. Rarely is the time of birth useful or needed or recorded. So why do you use the datetime datatype?

Comment: @SMor - Yes datetime type is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *id* is auto then you can do :

```
select p.*
from @person p
where exists (select 1 from @person p1 where p1.e_name = p.e_name and p.id <> p1.id);
```

However, you can also use `dob` instead of *id* :

```
select p.*
from @person p
where exists (select 1 from @person p1 where p1.e_name = p.e_name and p.dob <> p1.dob);
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion uses `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING`-clause:

The *mockup table* to simulate your issue

```
declare @person table (id int, e_name nvarchar(50), dob datetime)

INSERT @person VALUES (1,'Jack Hughens','19601102')
INSERT @person VALUES (2,'Tom Hughens', '19710108')
INSERT @person VALUES (3,'Sam Scallion','19601102')
INSERT @person VALUES (4,'Sam Scallion','19601101')
INSERT @person VALUES (5,'Paul Darty',  '19941019')
INSERT @person VALUES (6,'Paul Ashley', '19830921');
```

--The query

```
WITH FindNames AS
(
    SELECT p.e_name
    FROM @person p
    GROUP BY p.e_name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.dob)>1
)
SELECT p.*
FROM @person p
INNER JOIN FindNames n ON p.e_name=n.e_name;
```

the idea in short:

Using `COUNT(DISTINCT p.dob)` will count **differing** values only.
The CTE will return names, where you see more than one, but different DOBs.
The final SELECT will JOIN the CTE's set, hence using it as filter.